# Crystal reports multiple rows in group section

Tags: crystal-reports, report, rows

I have a report that looks like the following:

```
 ->Page Header
   **ColTitle1     ColTitle2   ColTitle3     ColTitle4    ColTitle5    ColTitle6**
 ->Group Header (On Table1.column1)
      col1          col2        col3          Col4         Col5         Col6
 ->Details Section
       xyz           xyz         xyz           
 ->Group Footer
       empty
```

I want that the **col3** column of the group to have multiple rows (that include some extra data about the group record from another table) like this:

```
 ->Page Header
   **ColTitle1     ColTitle2   ColTitle3     ColTitle4    ColTitle5    ColTitle6**
 ->Group Header (On Table1.column1)
      col1          col2        col3.row1       Col4         Col5         Col6
                                col3.row2                                         
                                col3.row3 
 ->Details Section
       xyz           xyz         xyz           
 ->Group Footer
       empty
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried Sub report. But couldn't do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use a subreport, with a link on `Table1.column1 = Table1.column1`.

(**removed:** an alternative, partly implemented solution which would be complicated to implement correctly)

Comment: I hate using subreports but i think with the other solution you'll have a problem because the detail section will repeat for each group

Comment: Oh, you're right. Would probably require a combination of another suppress formula and a variable.

Comment: I got a subreport in place but the thing is there is no primary key thats common between both the tables. So cant link them.

Comment: Which rows do you want the subreport to display?

Comment: I want col3.row1, col3.row2 and col3.row3 that come from a separate table to be displayed in the subreport. And there  is no primary key common between the two tables.

Comment: If you want all the rows from the separate table, you don't need to use any subreport links.